# Is magnetic field is constant inside a spherical coil?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Imagine a sphere of radius $R$, centred at the origin (0,0,0).

We take a super-thin wire and start winding it on the surface of the sphere from one pole to another (let's assume poles are at $x=-R$ and $x=+R$), so that the windings are always parallel to x-z plane ("wire thickness" is negligible). So we are basically creating a "spherical solenoid".

The radius $y$ of such a coil will obviously depend on the axial coordinate $x$ as $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$.

Considering each turn of the wire as a single loop of radius $y(x)$, we can then use the well-known result for the magnetic field along the axis of a single current loop and integrate it (superposition of the fields of all turns) from $x=-R$ to $x=R$:

$$B_x\Bigg|_{x=a}=\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\int\limits_{-R}^{+R}\frac{2\pi(R^2-x^2)}{((a-x)^2+R^2-x^2)^{3/2}}dx = \frac{\mu_0I}{2}\int\limits_{-R}^{+R}\frac{R^2-x^2}{(a^2-2ax+R^2)^{3/2}}dx$$

where $I$ is the current (Amp/metre) in the coil per metre of $x$-length, so that $Idx$ is the current, Amperes, in each turn.

This is pretty easy to calculate numerically e.g. for each location along the $x-$axis of the coil $a=-R...+R$ and some values of $R$ and $I$ and we get <strike>super</strike> quite uniform distribution of magnetic field inside the sphere along the axis. I assume it also should be pretty uniform off the axis as well. The figure below computed for <strike>1000</strike> 100 turns of wire (10000 Ampere-turns). Dashed lines show the size of the spherical coil. Obviously, increasing the number of turns further will improve the "end-effects" and make $B_x(x)$ almost step-wise at the poles.

[image]

I was wondering if that integral above can be taken analytically to prove it is a constant value (except the $x=-R$ and $x=+R$ of course)

Comment: The integral can be done analytically, by hand. Change the integration variable to make the denominator $u^{3/2}$.

Comment: Your description of the geometry seems confused. If the windings are parallel to the $xy$ plane, then the poles would be at $z=\pm R$, not $x=\pm R$.

Comment: my "axis" of the sphere is Ox, so the poles at which I start to wind the wire and end winding are at $x=\pm R$. I tried integrating by substitution, you still end up with $x^2$ in the numerator... like $..=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2}\int_{-R}^{+R}\frac{R^2-x^2}{u^{3/2}}\frac{du}{2}$

Comment: Then the windings are parallel to the $yz$ plane, not the $xy$ plane.

Comment: of course... will correct

Comment: When you change variables, you are supposed to write $x$ in terms of $u$ and $dx$ in terms of $du$. There is no $x$ remaining anywhere.

Comment: I also advise having access to a computer algebra program to double-check hand calculations.

Comment: I don't see how you can make x disappear in the numerator. $u=a^2-2ax+R^2$, $\therefore dx=-\frac{du}{2a}$, and $-\frac{\mu_0 I}{2} \int \frac{R^2-x^2}{u^{3/2} }\frac{du}{2a} $

Comment: Just solve for $x$ in terms of $u$.

Comment: Since your question is about an integral, it is a math question, not a physics one, so don’t be surprised if it gets closed as off-topic for PSE.

Comment: If $u =a^2−2ax+R$, then solve for $x$ and use that expression for the numerator.

Comment: that will render it even more complicated...

Comment: The number of terms (which is *only* in the single digits) is not what is relevant. What is relevant is whether the $u$ integrations are doable. They are. In fact, they are now “trivial” in the sense of being one of the first integrals you learn in a beginning calculus course.

Comment: OK, here we are: $B_x\Bigg|_{x=a}=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2}   \frac{2(R+a)^2 (R^2 -R a+a^2 )}{3 a^3 \sqrt{(R+a)^2 }}-\frac{2(R-a)^2 (R^2 +Ra+a^2)}{3a^3 \sqrt{(R-a)^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

$B_x\Bigg|_{x=a}=\frac{\mu_0 I}{3}  \left( \frac{(R+a)^2 (R^2 -R a+a^2 )}{ a^3 \sqrt{(R+a)^2 }}-\frac{(R-a)^2 (R^2 +Ra+a^2)}{a^3 \sqrt{(R-a)^2}}\right)$

$a$ here is the coordinate along the axis of the coil.

[image]

Dashed lines show the size of the sphere (of radius 1).

The result can be expanded:

$B_x\Bigg|_{x=a}=\frac{\mu_0I}{3}\left( \frac{a}{|R+a|}-\frac{a}{|R-a|}+\frac{R}{|R-a|}+\frac{R}{|R+a|}+\frac{R^3 }{a^2 |R-a| }+\frac{R^3 }{a^2 |R+a|}-\frac{R^4 }{a^3 |R-a|}+\frac{R^4 }{a^3 |R+a|}  \right)$

If $R=1$ the "shape" of the distribution can be simplified further to

$y(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{x}{ |x+1|}-\frac{x}{|x-1|}+\frac{1}{|x-1|}+\frac{1}{|x+1|}+\frac{1}{x^2 |x-1|}+\frac{1}{x^2 |x+1 |}-\frac{1}{x^3 |x-1 |}+\frac{1}{x^3|x+1|}\right]=...$

$...=\begin{cases} 
      1 & -1 <x<1  \\
      -\frac{1}{x^3} &x\le-1 \\
      \frac{1}{x^3} & x\ge 1  
   \end{cases}$

Comment: Clearly there is a further algebraic simplification which you haven’t done, since that complicated expression must simplify to the observed plotted constant inside the sphere. It also simplifies outside, although not to a constant.

Comment: You also haven’t explained why you are getting a numerical value for the field inside that is different from the plot in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments G.Smith! The different value of the field was just due to the different value of the current. I since checked it for the same value of Ampere-turns and it gives the same result. But then I decided to normalise it by the field value inside the coil (B_max).and changed both plots to look mostly similar and to show just the difference in "shape" of the curve. It can be simplified algebraically I guess, the form i left it in is just to show the result of integration and computing it between the limits $x=\pm R$

Comment: This answer does not explain how you did the integral. Simply presenting the result is not particularly useful.

Comment: *It can be simplified algebraically I guess* Yes, and you should do that because your expression is not obviously constant inside the sphere. As is, it is a low-quality answer because it does *not* answer your own question “to prove it is a constant value”.

Comment: As you pointed out earlier, this is not a Maths section, so I restrained from providing "by hand" solution (I actually did it on the computer :). I think the last expression gives the simplest form of the answer (at least to the given number of terms in the expansion) and it is "almost" constant inside the sphere. This function obviously is not continuous and exhibits discontinuities at $x=0$ and $x=\pm R$, but besides those points it is constant inside.

Comment: We don’t seem to be getting anywhere but that’s OK. I’ve downvoted and will not try further to get you to improve the answer.

Comment: by "almost constant" I meant that it has discontinuities

Comment: last addition: result represented as a piecewise function to make it clear that it is constant inside the sphere (see above). Thanks for your commentaries!

Comment: I’m glad that you got to the simplification. I’ve removed my downvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116625/discussion-between-alex-p-and-g-smith).